# How to fix the Entry box when adjusting height in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

So I have a issue for where I type it will be right at the middle which I want to start it at the beginning of the box.

```
entry_notfor = Entry(root, textvariable=number_notoffer, width=30, bg="#1f1e1e", fg="#ffffff")
entry_notfor.place(x=5, y=390, height=100)
```

this is what it looks like now:
[image]

Comment: Shouldn't Y be a much smaller number to get it up to the top?

Comment: no it will move the whole thing, and still will be typing at the middle of the box

Comment: Ok right. of course

Comment: try using the `Text` widget?

Comment: How Would I be able to use that Cool Cloud?

Comment: Take a look [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_text.htm)

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing you can do if you make the entry widget taller than it wants to be. An `Entry` widget is designed to be only one line tall. If you stretch it to be unnaturally tall, the text will always only appear centered vertically.

If your intent is to support multiline input then you should use a `Text` widget rather than an `Entry`.

Comment: So is there a possibility I can grab the users input? With textvariable, using text widget?

Comment: @TeisqI `txt.get(1.0,END)` would do the trick, but with more lines there is a different way, do some searches on the internet or Bryan can edit the answer with the `get()` method of `Text` too. More on [this](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2005-February/035669.html)

Comment: So for example I had something called``` number_offer = StringVar()``` would it be and did test_cookie = Text(root, textvariable=number_offer, width=20, height=50) would it work?

Comment: i dont think you need a variable for this

Comment: So it can grab it without textvariable

Comment: How would I be able to call the .get() method?

Comment: its fine, try and let me know and also look [here](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2005-February/035669.html)